# Relatively closed subsets of compact set is compact intuition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I was thinking about compactness and found the (I'm sure already well-known) property that relatively closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

The proof I found is the following:

Let $F \subseteq K \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a metric space and $K$ is a compact subset. Since $F$ is relatively closed in $K$ we have that $K \setminus F = K \cap H$ for some open $H \subseteq X$. Taking an open cover $\{G_\alpha\}$ of $F$ in $X$, we have $F \subseteq \cup_{\alpha}G_\alpha$. We also have $K = F \cup K\setminus F \subseteq (\cup_{\alpha}G_\alpha) \cup H$ which is an open cover of $K$ so by compactness there is a finite subcover. If this finite subcover includes $H$ then throw it out, if not then use it as is. This yields a finite subcover of $F$, so $F$ is compact since the original open cover was arbitrary.

Does this proof make sense? I felt it kind of odd since being open and closed is a relative property and so $F$ being closed with respect to $K$ doesn't mean it has to be closed with respect to $X$ but compactness with respect to $X$ forces $F$ to be closed.

Comment: Yes, closed subsets of compacts are compact. That $X$ or $K$ is metric is not needed, as your proof shows. What about compact subsets of compacts, are they always closed?

Comment: Yes, but I suppose what I was confused about is - does it matter of $F$ is relatively closed in $K$ or does the "closed subsets of compacts are compact" still apply? And yes, I believe compact subsets of compacts are closed since being compact implies being closed (in the original space).

Comment: Yes, you used that $F$ is closed in $K$. That condition cannot be dropped since, for example $(0,1)$ is not compact in the compact $[0,1]$. If the topology is finite, for example, and doesn't include all subsets (not the discrete topology), then all subsets are compact, but not all of them are closed.

Comment: So basically relatively closed subsets of compact subsets (that are subsets of some larger space) are just closed with respect to the larger space?

Comment: The larger space $X$ is not needed for anything. That $F$ is relatively closed in $K$ just means that $F$ is closed in the space $K$ with the topology  induced as a subspace of $X$.

Comment: If  X is Hausdorff then compact subsets of X are closed in X.  But there are finite and infinite spaces in which every subset is compact but not every subset is closed.